# Matrix input from a text file(python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, input, matrix, integer, text-files

Im trying to find a way to be able to input a matrix from a text file;

for example, a text file would contain

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And it would make a matrix with those numbers and put it in matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

And then this has to be compatible with the way I print the matrix:

```
 print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in matrix]))
```

So far,I tried this

chemin = input('entrez le chemin du fichier')

```
        path = input('enter file location') 

        f = open ( path , 'r')
        matrix = [ map(int,line.split(','))) for line in f if line.strip() != "" ]
```

All it does is return me a map object and return an error when I try to print the matrix.

What am I doing wrong? Matrix should contain the matrix read from the text file and not map object,and **I dont want to use external library such as numpy**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension as such:

**`myfile.txt`:**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9


>>> matrix = open('myfile.txt').read()
>>> matrix = [item.split() for item in matrix.split('\n')[:-1]]
>>> matrix
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
>>>
```

You can also create a function for this:

```
>>> def matrix(file):
...     contents = open(file).read()
...     return [item.split() for item in contents.split('\n')[:-1]]
... 
>>> matrix('myfile.txt')
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping; I tried your list comprehension,however,I created a file with the matrix 1 2 3,under those,4 5 6 and under 4 5 6, 7 8 9; It doest work but only write 1 2 3 and 4 5 6 in the matrix, 7 8 9 is not showing/saved?

Comment: I removed [:-1] from your code and now it works as I wish; what was [:-1] for? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is working with both python2(e.g. Python 2.7.10) and python3(e.g. Python 3.6.4)

```
rows=3
cols=3
with open('in.txt') as f:
   data = []
   for i in range(0, rows):
      data.append(list(map(int, f.readline().split()[:cols])))
print (data)
```